# How do I use doctest with a shell application from setuptools (entry point)?

Tags: python, module, setuptools, doctest

I have a module with a bunch of functions. One of them should call `testmod` (or the appropriate [doctest](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/doctest.html) function) to test all the other functions in the module, provided a certain condition is met.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# Let's call this file 'mymodule.py'

import sys

def to_be_tested():
    '''\
    >>> to_be_tested()
    2
    '''
    return 1 # Would fail, but doesn't get tested

# ... more functions with doctest strings ...

def main():
    if '--test' in sys.argv: # Test all functions in this file
        import doctest
        doctest.testmod(verbose=True) # Doesn't work with setuptools
        exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The example works fine, when run as a shell script, e.g. as `/home/confus/mymodule.py --test`, but not using the entry point specified in `setup.py`. In the latter case, e.g. run by `mymoduleapp --test`, only `main()` is tested (and passes every time, because no test is defined in its docstring).

```
# In 'setup.py'
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    ...,
    entry_points='''
       [console_scripts]
       mymoduleapp=mymodule:main
)
'''
```

Comment: So... What's the question?

Comment: Ummm... I just copy-pasted your code, ran it with `--test` parameter and it actually works, failing test for `to_be_tested()`. And it recognizes all three items to test (also `__main__` and `__main__.main`).

Comment: Weird, for me `to_be_tested()` is just ingnored. Are you on python 2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: Tested on both 2.7.10 and 3.5.2, works perfectly. The only thing I needed to change in your code is to add `import sys`. Okay, so you don't get any output at all, or `testmod()` recognizes `__main__` at least?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123383/discussion-between-pavel-gurkov-and-con-f-use).